# How do I optionally render a section in ASP.Net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

On my website, I have a section (a floating sidebar) that I want rendered only for a sub-set of users (admins). I'm hoping that I can put the logic in the master layout for determining if the section should be shown or not but that causes an error on the page if the section isn't rendered.

Example code - Layout.cshtml...

```
... code ...
@if(user.IsAdmin) {
    @RenderSection("AdminSidebar", false)
}
```

Example code - MyPage.cshtml...

```
@section AdminSidebar {
    ... code ...
}
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work without having to put the logic in all of the child pages?

As a note, IsSectionDefined("AdminSidebar") only works in the layout file. It doesn't work in the page to test if the section is available or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if this is not abusing the framework, but if you're really inclined to go that way you could try the following:

```
@{
    if(user.IsAdmin) {
        @RenderSection("AdminSidebar", false)
    } 
    else {
        RenderSection("AdminSidebar", false).WriteTo(TextWriter.Null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever. I like it. I wish that the MVC framework just ignored sections that weren't defined instead of throwing errors, but this allows me to define the section the way I want to.

Comment: @Brian But why not using the renderPartial as suggested by itsmatt, which is much cleaner?

Comment: Because then I would have to create a partial for every page that I want to add a sidebar too (it's contextual based on the page).

Comment: You may have to wrap this section with IsSectionDefined("AdminSideBar") to account for pages that do not define the section.

Answer (score 2):

In my _Layout.cshtml file I did something like this:

```
@if(user.IsAdmin)
{
   @Html.Partial("SideBar")
}
```

to avoid having to have all of the child pages have to deal with the optional section in essentially the same manner.  When I first tried the optional section thing, I found that I was repeating myself in the child pages, at least in my implementation.

Where I've used the `@RenderSection` call for optional sections, it has generally been to provide page-specific stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately each page can have different elements in the sidebar (it's basically a set of contextual tools) so this wouldn't work.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this answer, it should be `@if(user.IsAdmin){ Html.RenderPartial("SideBar"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Using a section for something that is conditional based on the users permission level feels a little dirty to me. I would use RenderPartial(user) and put the logic in the partial.

```
    @if(user.IsAdmin) {
       ..code..
     }
```